# Can't use document.getElementById().innerHTML to rewrite the original html

Tags: javascript, html

I am tring to add some content after the original content, but the new content will cover the original content everytime...What wrong in this case? (Sorry for my terrible english...)

```
var originaltext = document.getElementById("id").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = originaltext + "newtext";
```

One more thing,I tried to use alert to show the "originalltext", but it have nothing to show.

```
alert(originaltext);
```

Comment: What element is `cartzone`?

Comment: As a side note, there's no need of `.toString()` here, `.innerHTML` is already a string.

Comment: Please don't edit your _code_ according to comments, now the comments look irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

your code looks ok to me. I made a jsfiddle for you just to see that it works http://jsfiddle.net/3mqsLweo/

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('test');
var originalText = myElement.innerHTML.toString();
myElement.innerHTML = originalText+" new text";
```

check that you only have one element with the id "cartzone"

Answer (score 0):

A simple and fast way to do this is to concatenate the old value with the new.

```
document.getElementById('myid').innerHTML += " my new text here"
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem usually occurs when the rest of your code is poorly written and contains errors or when the same ID is used several times.
I had the same problems in the past.

you have tow options:

1. check the rest of your code (validate)
2. use jQuery - I don't know how, but it works every time.